# Centering responsive svg circle in container

Tags: html, css, svg

### [Test page](http://jsbin.com/lurepim/edit?html,css,output)

#### Markup:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400"  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <g>
        <circle r="70" class="circle-back" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

#### CSS

```
.doughnutChart{
    text-align:center;
    padding:50% 1em 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    > svg{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left:0; right:0;
        margin: auto;

        g{ transform:rotate(270deg) translate(-88px, 200px); }
    }

    circle{ fill: none; }
    .circle-back { stroke:#EEE; stroke-width: 5px; }
}
```

As you can see in the test page, I am trying to position a responsive circle with some radius, and I want it to position itself in the middle of the container, regardless the width of the container. It would be even better if the circle also fit itself to the height of the container.

There seem to be a problem with css `translate` using percentages on the `g` element, which prevents me from just doing `translate(-50%, -50%)`

---

*This is a very simplified version of what I have, since in my code it's a doughnut chart, this is why it has this `rotate` transform to it*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the SVG to be the size of the circle you need to set the viewbox to twice the radius and determine a center point.

> The circle is centered in cx , cy and has a radius of r. cx, cy and r are attributes of the  element.

```css
svg {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
circle {
  fill: none;
}
.circle-back {
  stroke: #EEE;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 140 140" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <g>
    <circle r="70" cx="50%" cy="50%" class="circle-back" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

You always need to determine the center of the circle using `cx` and `cy` which will default to 0,0 (left top) if not stated.

Alternatively, for a viewbox-independent centered circle you could use a % radius.

```css
svg {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid plum;
}
circle {
  fill: none;
}
.circle-back {
  stroke: #EEE;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 140 140" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <g>
    <circle r="50%" cx="50%" cy="50%" class="circle-back" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

In your original code.

```css
svg {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
circle {
  fill: none;
}
.circle-back {
  stroke: #EEE;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <g>
    <circle r="70" cx="200" cy="200" class="circle-back" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

See the difference?

Reference [**Link**](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/circle-element.html) with tutorials & video

Comment: Hey. sorry but this is not exactly what I need. first, I have a stroke, not fill, and second, it doesn't work at all when i apply what you've said to the demo page. Would you be kind enough to see why? - mind the the `g` is rotated.

Comment: Added your classes to the examples and it clearly does work...at least in Chrome. What browser are you using an which implementation of the 3 are you using.